# Part of script wont run when named main.py or boot.py

Tags: pi-pico, home-automation, micropython

I am using a RaspiPico W RP 2040 with micropython and Im trying to autorun this script when Pico is powered. I plan on powering the pico with an external power brick.

The script is a multithreading process which runs a server on one thread to receive data on the socket while the other thread drives the display.
I can get the script to work with Thonny and I can see normal output but when I name it boot.py or main.py, I see no output. Somehow I can still send messages to the webserver on the Pico. What am I doing wrong that it only works when connected to Thonny?

```
import _thread
from time import sleep
from machine import Pin, SPI
from gc import collect
import jpegdec
from pimoroni_bus import SPIBus
from picographics import PicoGraphics, DISPLAY_PICO_DISPLAY, PEN_RGB332
from web_test import connect_WLAN, open_socket, data_poll
import st7789py


spLock = _thread.allocate_lock() # creating semaphore
global data_buffer
data_buffer = []


def init_display():
# Incase picographics fails to initalise the display, use ST7789py driver to initiate display
    try:
        screen_width = 135
        screen_height = 240
        screen_rotation = 1
        spi = SPI(1, baudrate=31250000, polarity=1, phase=1, bits=8, firstbit=SPI.MSB, sck=Pin(10), mosi=Pin(11))
        screen = st7789py.ST7789(spi, screen_width, screen_height, reset=Pin(12, Pin.OUT), cs=Pin(9, Pin.OUT), dc=Pin(8, Pin.OUT), backlight=Pin(13, Pin.OUT), rotation=screen_rotation)
    except:
        print("failed display initialzation")
    
    spibus = SPIBus(cs=9, dc=8, sck=10, mosi=11)
    display = PicoGraphics(DISPLAY_PICO_DISPLAY, bus=spibus, pen_type=PEN_RGB332, rotate=180)
    return display



def image_screen(path, max_images):
    spLock.acquire() # acquiring semaphore
    display = init_display()
    display.clear()
    collect()
    j = jpegdec.JPEG(display)
    for n in range(1, max_images):
        j.open_file(path + str(n)+".jpeg")
        j.decode(0, 0, jpegdec.JPEG_SCALE_FULL)
        display.update()
        sleep(0.3)
    spLock.release()


def text_screen_list():
    spLock.acquire() # acquiring semaphore
    over_temp_flag = False
    display = init_display()
    WIDTH, HEIGHT = display.get_bounds()
    WHITE = display.create_pen(255, 255, 255)
    display.clear()
    try:
        data_package = eval(data_buffer)
        display.set_pen(WHITE)
        display.set_font("bitmap8")
        if int(data_package[0])>39:
            over_temp_flag = True
        display.text(("CPU:   "+data_package[0]), 0, 0, WIDTH, 3)
        display.text(("GPU:   "+data_package[1]), 0, 25, WIDTH, 3)
        display.text(("M.2:   "+data_package[2]), 0, 50, WIDTH, 3)
        display.text(("MAS:   "+data_package[3]), 0, 75, WIDTH, 3)
        display.update()
        sleep(1) #keep the numbers on the screen
    except:
        pass
    
    spLock.release()
    collect()
    return over_temp_flag

def engage_screen():
    while True:
        for _ in range(3):
            over_temp_flag = text_screen_list()
            collect()
        if over_temp_flag is True:
            image_screen("/boost/image", 5)
        else:
            image_screen("/idle/image", 5)
    return None

second_thread = _thread.start_new_thread(engage_screen, ())

def core1_thread():
    global data_buffer
    connect_WLAN()
    comm_socket = open_socket()
    while True:
        data_buffer = data_poll(comm_socket)
        collect()
    return None

print("Resuming Core0 processes")
core1_thread()
```

More details:
Display: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Pico-LCD-1.14#Run_in_Raspberry_Pi

firmware: pimoroni-picow-v1.19.2-micropython.uf2
https://github.com/pimoroni/pimoroni-pico/releases

Comment: so you found that the system might have  some reserved filenames ... it is unclear why you would think that there is anything else wrong, other than the choice of filenames

Comment: I think what I was trying to explain was why only the web server on one core would execute fine while the other thread would not initiate. From what I understand, the pico microcontroller with micropython firmware will autorun any script named main.py in a loop and boot.py a one time on power on. I was wondering if the autorun functionality has some kind of overhead that eats away at the RAM and causes my script to initialise only one core.